# "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end" For my uni registration assignment

Tags: php, html, parse-error

I am new to php so I used a Youtube tutorial to create this script, however the uploader seems to have disappeared so I cannot ask him any questions. My login form seems to work fine but the registration form is where I am having trouble

I have removed all html from code and all error else statements to try eliminate the error message but I cant seem to find it. Error always occurs at the end of my script.

Any suggestions

```
        <?php

        if ( $_POST['registerbtn'] ) {
    //makes sure email, username is valid
    $getuser = $_POST['user'];
    $getemail = $_POST['email'];
    $getpass = $_POST['pass'];
    $getretypepass = $_POST['retypepass'];

    if (!isset($getuser))
    {
        $error = "user not set ";
    } 

    if ($getuser) {
        if($getemail) {
            if($getpass) {
                if ($getretypepass) {
        require("connection.php");

                            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM          users WHERE username ='$getuser'");
                            $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
                            if ($numrows == 0) {
                            $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email ='$getemail'");
                            $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
                            if ($numrows == 0) {

                                $password = md5(md5("19Dvdnj".$password."jndfFf20"));
                                $date = date("F d, Y");
                                $code = md5(rand());

                                mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES ('', '$getuser', '$password', '$getmail', '0', '$code', '$date')");

                                $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$getuser'");
                                $numrows =mysql_num_rows($query);
                                if ($numrows == 1) { 

                                $site ="http://www.inn.leedsmet.ac.uk/~c3314283/iis/register.php";
                                $webmaster = "admin@leedsmet.com";
                                $headers = "From: $webmaster";
                                $subject ="Activate your Account";
                                $message = "Thanks for registering. Click below to activate your account.\n";
                                $message .= "$site/activate.php?user=$getuser&code=$code";
                                $message .= "You must activate your account to login";

                                if (mail($getmail, $subject, $message, $headers)){
                                    $errormsg = "You have been registered you must activate your account sent from the the activation link sent to<b>$getemail</b>";
                                    $getuser = "";
                                    $getemail = "";
                                }



                            mysql_close();





        $form ="<form action='register.php' method='post'>
        <table>
        <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><font color='red'>$errormsg</font></td>
        </tr>

<tr>
    <td>Username:</td>
    <td><input type='text' name='user' value ='$getuser'/></td>
</tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Email:</td>
        <td><input type='text' name='email' value ='$getemail'/></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
    <td>Password:</td>
    <td><input type='password' name='pass' value =''/></td>
        </tr>       
    <tr>
    <td>Retype:</td>
    <td><input type='password' name='retypepass' value =''/></td>
        </tr>   
    <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type='submit' name='registerbtn' value ='Register'/></td>
        </tr>   
        </table>
        </form>";
        {
        echo $form;
        }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try autoformating (auto-indent) your code.  If you do not have an editor that allows that, get one such as [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) or [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/). :-)  It will save you a lot of time in similar situations; instead of trying to locate the problem in such situations, after autoformating problems will stare you in the face. :-)

I believe you are missing around six closing braces `}` (not sure I counted the number of unclosed `if`s correctly) after the

```
{
    echo $form;
}
```

Obviously if this is the case something terribly wrong has happened and it may take more than putting some `}`s there to heal your code.

This could be a copy&paste problem.  Maybe you did not copy the last few lines of the code you found in the Youtube tutorial you mention.

Answer (score 1):

Using any code editor with syntax highlighting (such as Notepad++) will clearly show you that you are missing a `}`.